# Use the information out of Contact Form 7 WordPress Plugin in the Email the Plugin sends

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, contacts

So I am working with WordPress right now and installed the Contact Form 7 Plugin. Creating the correct contact form is the simple work with that. But I dont understand how I can collect the input information from the contact form and put it in the e-mail send by the plugin. Everything I recieve as a e-mail is an empty mail with the link to my site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use the name of your field in square brackets.

For example, if you've got a form such as:

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Subject<br />
    [text your-subject 80/] </p>

<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message 80x10] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Then you can refer to these fields in the message body as follows. Use the same field names as you used in the form, you can use any field names you like.

From: [**your-name**] <[**your-email**]>

Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[**your-message**]

Comment: Thanks for your help I just did not use the same tags in the form and the output form. Now everythings works perfectly